# How do I get a multi-field values?

Tags: 7

I have content type called "sample", where i have field called 'user detail' which is a multifield. I'm using [multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) module to get this. 
  I'm creating a view for display sample content type contents, but i'm not able to fetch multifield fields in view table.Can anybody help me in fetching multifield values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this puppy does not come with Views integration, perhaps it will soon in the near future.

For now, you will need to patch it, with [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041533#comment-11246925).